# Does PHP Optimize Out Always True/False Blocks

Tags: php

Does PHP optimze out statments that are always true or does it evaluate the statment every time?
e.g.

`config.php`

```
const $enableFeature = true;
```

`app.php`

```
include("config.php");
if($enableFeature){
   //do the stuff
}
//or even
if(1==1){
   //do the stuff
}
```

will these IF statments be evaluated every time?

I suppose the answer could change between versions of PHP as well.

Comment: you can use one of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146894/how-to-see-php-bytecode-file) to see the compiled byte code.

Comment: in your examples it doesn't really matter since the if tests that could be skipped take roughly 0% of the execution time.   `if (test) { foo() }` vs. `foo()`

Comment: Unless this code is in a loop with many iterations, the difference is negligible.

Comment: @DaveS i mean yea. this is obviously not a real world example. but its the concept itself, does it, even if negligible? Most compiled languages do that, and even some JIT compiled languages like Javascript (V8) do.

Comment: From my understanding, back when PHP had a [single-pass compilation process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553252/231316) this was mostly not possible. With the [introduction of an AST](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/abstract_syntax_tree) this could be now be done, but I don't think was. Finally, at the [JIT level](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jit) some optimizations can be [further enabled](https://php.watch/articles/jit-in-depth)